# angular js calling ng-init on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling ng-int() on ng-repeat like this:

```
<ul class="title_page1" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
  <li  ng-init='some(val.id);'  ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu">{{val.name}}</span><span>{{size}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

I have three elements in menu, by this ng-init is getting called for each ng-repeat but {{size}} from some(val.id). I am getting same size for all the 3 elements. Please kelp me in sorting out this.

```
$scope.some={function(id){

     return $http({
         url : 'url+id',
         method : 'GET',
         async : false,
     }).success(function(data) { 
        $scope.size = data.length;
    });    
};
$scope.menu=[{java,php,micro}];
```

And this the thins I am doing but the size i am getting for all the elements is same.
but i have seen in the google but i did not get any result from google

Answer (score 3):

You are retrieving the data for 3 id's, however your saving them in the scope where your controller resides, which can only have one `size` variable. What I would do is save the size variable into the val object.

```
<ul class="title_page1" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
  <li  ng-init='some(val);'  ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu">{{val.name}}</span><span>{{val.size}}</span></li>
</ul>

$scope.some={function(val){

     return $http({
         url : 'url'+val.id,
         method : 'GET',
         async : false,
     }).success(function(data) { 
        val.size = data.length;
    });    
};
$scope.menu=[{java,php,micro}];
```